# Ffmpeg Convert Speed

Tags: ffmpeg

I convert movie(720p to m720p) with ffmpeg slow preset. I have two server. Having E-1230-processor. 7 frames per second can process. I have tried with Amazon Web Services EC2. There is the same speed. What is the zencoder.com, encoding.com rationale?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand your question. 7 fps at the `slow` preset isn't unusual and entirely depends on your hardware—online encoding services are of course much faster when they use server grids and distributed encoding.

Comment: I'm sorry, I know little English. Same speed as converted the Amazon ec2 :( How can I accelerate? how the hardware required?

Comment: Try `-preset ultrafast` instead. Other than that, you obviously need a speedy, multi-core CPU to encode fast. Hard disk speed and RAM are not as important here.

Comment: You're always help. Thank you very much :) processors feature: 4 physical, 4 virtual. ultrafast preset quality is deteriorating.

Comment: Yes, there is always a very big tradeoff between quality and speed – no way around that, unfortunately.

Comment: movies to separate the parts. Can process different servers? The logic of zencoder be? such as load balancing?